# Как открыть Socket используя ip и port которые вводит пользователь

Tags: java, android

Есть клиент, в нем кнопка `button` и два текстовых поля ввода `IpAddress` и `NewPort`.

Помогите сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки прочитать данные введенные в `IpAddress` и `NewPort` и запустить `Socket` используя эти данные. Сама программа проверена и работает, если `ip` и `port` задать в коде.

```
Button button;
TextView IpAddress;
TextView NewPort;

private Socket socket;

private int SERVERPORT = 0;
private String SERVER_IP = null;

ClientThread client;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle.savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
IpAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IpAdd);
NewPort = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PortAdd);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       SERVER_IP = IpAdress.getText().toString();
       SERVERPORT = NewPort.getText().length();

       client = new ClientThread();
       Thread thread = new Thread(client);
       thread.start();
    }
});


class ClientThread implements Runnable {
PrintWriter out;

@Override
public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
}

public void sendMessage(String str) {
    out.write(str);
    out.flush();
}
}
```

Comment: Для ввода текста надо использовать `EditText`. Замените в коде и разметке `TextView` на `EditText` и всё должно заработать.

Comment: Надо все еще перестать брать номер порта как длину строки (хотя может это инновационный интерфейс)

Comment: @zRrr, как вы и советовали я попробовал разные варианты с Integer.parseInt и добился успеха в таком виде:  `TextView IpAddress; TextView NewPort; SERVER_IP = IpAddress.getText().toString(); SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(NewPort.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте для ввода данных EditText.

```
EditText editTextIp;
EditText editTextPort;

SERVER_IP = editTextPort.getText().toString();
SERVERPORT = Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString());
```